# In Swift to safely access JSON Dictionary with arbitrary structure of keys and values?

Tags: json, swift

I am attempting to read keys and values out of a JSON object that does not have a defined structure. The JSON looks similar to:

```
{
    "content":"me,menu_cta,page",
    "me": {
        "email": "person@example.com",
        "first_name": "Jordan"
    },
    "menu_cta": {
        "menu_text": "Tap here"
    },
    "page": {
        "how_it_works": "Make sure you're tapping the right spots.'",
        "page_icon": "https://www.example.com/button.png",
        "terms": "Terms and Conditions"
    }
}
```

I don't think I can use Codeable since I'm unsure at compile-time what the keys will be inside the Dictionary and I'm also unsure if the values will be Strings or Dictionaries. The keys in the JSON that are read are dynamic based on user interaction.

I can start by setting up the Dictionary object:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
  if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
    self.prefetchDictionary = content
  }
}
```

But when trying to read any data, ideally I would like to ask for `page.how_it_works` but I think the best method for doing this looks like this:

```
if let pageGenericDictionary = prefetchDictionary?["page"] {
  if let pageDictionary = prefetchDictionary as? [String:String] {
    headerText.text = pageDictionary["how_it_works"]
  }
}
```

Is this the easiest way?  Is there any method to write a simple function that could traverse down easily with definitions like `page.how_it_works` or `me.email`?

I am trying to avoid including a 3rd party library to achieve this.

Comment: "I am trying to avoid including a 3rd party library to achieve this." Why? SwiftyJSON does exactly this. If you don't want to use it, I guess you can still study how they achieved it and learn from them.

Comment: your question is a bit too big for single SO answer, but this should help: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 (basically you can do what you want, and you can have `page.how_it_works` without any 3-rd party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, how arbitrary is it? The above suggests that this is exactly `[String: [String: String]]`, which is `Decodable`, and you should use `JSONDecoder` rather than `JSONSerialization` (you should generally avoid `JSONSerialization`):

```
let dict = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [String: String]].self, from: json)
```

If the actual *structure* is arbitrary, then I suggest an arbitrary JSON decoder. Simplified version here ([full version](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/d91175be2f737aca7ad476759948666e)):

```swift
enum JSON: Codable {
    struct Key: CodingKey, Hashable {
        let stringValue: String
        init(_ string: String) { self.stringValue = string }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue) }
        var intValue: Int? { return nil }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }

    case string(String)
    case number(Double) // FIXME: Split Int and Double
    case object([Key: JSON])
    case array([JSON])
    case bool(Bool)
    case null

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) { self = .string(string) }
        else if let number = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Double.self) { self = .number(number) }
        else if let object = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self) {
            var result: [Key: JSON] = [:]
            for key in object.allKeys {
                result[key] = (try? object.decode(JSON.self, forKey: key)) ?? .null
            }
            self = .object(result)
        }
        else if var array = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            var result: [JSON] = []
            for _ in 0..<(array.count ?? 0) {
                result.append(try array.decode(JSON.self))
            }
            self = .array(result)
        }
        else if let bool = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Bool.self) { self = .bool(bool) }
        else if let isNull = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decodeNil(), isNull { self = .null }
        else { throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
                                                                       debugDescription: "Unknown JSON type")) }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        switch self {
        case .string(let string):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(string)
        case .number(let number):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(number)
        case .bool(let bool):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(bool)
        case .object(let object):
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
            for (key, value) in object {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            }
        case .array(let array):
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
            for value in array {
                try container.encode(value)
            }
        case .null:
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }

    subscript(key: String) -> JSON? {
        guard let jsonKey = Key(stringValue: key),
            case .object(let object) = self,
            let value = object[jsonKey]
            else { return nil }
        return value
    }

    var stringValue: String? {
        switch self {
        case .string(let string): return string
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    var doubleValue: Double? {
        switch self {
        case .number(let number): return number
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        switch self {
        case .number(let number): return Int(number)
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> JSON? {
        switch self {
        case .array(let array): return array[index]
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    var boolValue: Bool? {
        switch self {
        case .bool(let bool): return bool
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

With that, you get the syntax:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSON.self, from: json)
let str: String? = result["page"]?["how_it_works"]?.stringValue
```

If you really want a dot-style syntax, you can get that with `@dynamicMemberLookup`:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
enum JSON: Codable {

    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> JSON {
        return self[member] ?? .null
    }

    ... the rest is the same ...
```

That would give you the syntax:

```
let x = result.page.how_it_works.stringValue
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to elaborate on the answer. Bonus points for bringing the `@dynamicMemberLookup` attribute, I just learned yet a new thing of Swift!